# How to get a tag which is present in div tag in python?

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a website http://i.cantonfair.org.cn/en/expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=411 using python.
I want get a link present inside a div tag in which there is two a tag like:

```
<div id="main_category">
  <div class="tit1"><a href="#" onclick="ExpandStage(1);"><strong>Phase 1</strong><br />April 15 - 19</a></div>
  <ul id="phase1">   
    <li><a href="expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=411">Consumer Electronics and Information Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=412">Electronic and Electrical Products</a></li>
```

and I want only all the a tag like

```
<a href="expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=411">Consumer Electronics and Information Products</a>
```

.Also How can I use regex to find the those URL ?

I am trying like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib.request
r = urllib.request.urlopen('http://i.cantonfair.org.cn/en/expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=410').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
letters = soup.find_all("div",{"id":"main_category"})
for element in letters:
categories = element.a.get_text()
print (categories)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using python 2.7, and the following works for me. Python 3 can use the same approach. Hope it helps:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib2 import urlopen
r = urlopen('http://i.cantonfair.org.cn/en/expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=410').read()
soup = bs(r, "lxml")
lis = soup.find_all("li")
hrefs = [c.a['href'] for c in lis]
print hrefs
```